# Problem passing SSH arguments into Windows Terminal using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh

I am trying to write a small putty replacement using powershell. I am having trouble passing the SSH command in, here is what I have:

The outgrid opens and I click on a server, but its not connecting. I get a new Windows terminal window with this text:

`[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching` "ssh root@server1"']`

I would like it to open a new tab in my existing WT session, and pass ssh root@server, then I can enter the PW and connect.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

```
# ssh-connect.ps1
$servers = @(
    "server1",
    "server2",
    "server3"
)

# Create an array to store the data for Out-GridView
$data = @()

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $data += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Server = $server
    }
}

$selectedServer = $data | Out-GridView -Title "Select a server" -PassThru
if ($selectedServer) {
    # Construct the SSH command
    $sshCommand = "ssh root@$($selectedServer.Server)"

    # Execute the Windows Terminal command using the call operator
    & wt new-tab -p PowerShell -d . -H $sshCommand
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not construct your SSH command *as a single string*, because PowerShell passes it as a *single argument* (enclosed in `"..."`) to [`wt.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments), the Windows Terminal CLI, whereas the latter expects a command (line) to be specified as *individual arguments*.

Therefore:

```bash
# Note how ssh and its argument are specified as separate arguments.
wt new-tab -p PowerShell `; split-pane -H ssh "root@$($selectedServer.Server)"
```

Note:

- `-d .` was omitted, because it is redundant (the caller's current directory is used by default).
- In order to use `-H` to create a horizontally split pane, you need the `split-pane` subcommand.
- Multiple `wt.exe` subcommands must be separated with `;` and because `;` is also a *PowerShell* metacharacter, it must be escaped as `` `; `` (`';'` or `";"` would work too).
- The lower horizontal pane created with `split-pane` uses your *default* Windows Terminal in terms of styling and doesn't actually create a *shell* session - it executes the command given directly in the pane.

  - To use the *styling* of a different profile, simply use another `-p` argument, in the context of the `split-pane` subcommand; e.g.:

    ```bash
    wt new-tab -p PowerShell `; split-pane -H -p PowerShell ssh "root@$($selectedServer.Server)"
    ```

Comment: Thanks so much! Yup that does it, and I really appreciate the great explanations also, that helps me wrap my head around it. Again, thanks!